# Does this activity have an official name?

Tags: architecture

I run a development team and when we design, for instance, a new workflow in the cloud where there is a chain of dependency between resources, I often take the initial design and run a session with the team specifically focused on working out potential failure scenarios for the proposed solution.  This is intended to identify whether we've covered our bases and have a 'good' solution.  The question is, does this activity have a specific name or is it part of a wider discipline?  For us it's part of the design phase of solutions planning but so often I come to realise that activities we've evolved into as a team actually have a name and set approach (often with a moment of "darn, wish we knew this was called X before and you do it this way").

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a name for it in Software however if you want to borrow from other engineering fields it sounds a little like a [HAZOP](https://safetyculture.com/topics/hazop/) (Hazard and Operability) meeting or straight up Risk Assessment.

Back when I worked in chemical plants we had meetings where we would walk through the whole system to identify ways in which it could fail and what mitigations we should take. The underlying principle is the same in software, take a look at the design, figure out what can go wrong and whether which layer we want the code to handle it in or whether we should stop the world when we encounter that error.

If anyone tries to judge you point out that Agile and it's friends have their roots in manufacturing too.